# Problem with matrix differentiation and vec operator

Tags: calculus, matrices, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, vector-spaces

I have to solve the following:

\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial{log|\Sigma|}}{\partial{vec(\Sigma)}}
\end{equation}
where $\Sigma$ is a symmetric matrix, and $|\Sigma|$ is the determinant.

I know that $\frac{\partial{log|\Sigma|}}{\partial{\Sigma}}=\Sigma^{-1}$ so with the chain rule:
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial{log|\Sigma|}}{\partial{vec(\Sigma)}}=\frac{\partial{log|\Sigma|}}{\partial{\Sigma}}
\frac{\partial{\Sigma}}{\partial{vec(\Sigma)}}=\Sigma^{-1}\frac{\partial{\Sigma}}{\partial{vec(\Sigma})}
\end{equation}

but i'm stuck here with $\frac{\partial{\Sigma}}{\partial{vec(\Sigma})}$, I don't know how to continue.
Can you help me?

Comment: Rather than the gradient, work with the equivalent differential expression
$$\eqalign{
\def\S{\Sigma}
\def\vc{\operatorname{vec}}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
d\log\det\LR{\S} &= \S^{-1}:d\S \;\,=\; \vc\LR{\S^{-1}}:\vc\LR{d\S} \\ 
\frac{\partial\log\det\LR{\S}}{\partial\vc\LR{\S}}  &= \vc\LR{\S^{-1}} \\ 
}$$
where $(:)$ denotes the [Frobenius product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product#Dyadics_and_matrices)

Comment: Use `\log` and `\mbox{vec}` instead.